# Prove existence of $\lim_{t \to \infty } \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin{tx}}{x} d x$

Tags: calculus, integration

What's an easy way to show that given $t \in \mathbb{R}$
$$\lim_{t \to \infty } \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin{tx}}{x} d x$$ exists and is finite?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579254/let-b0-evaluate-lim-n-to-infty-intb-0-frac-sin-nxnxdx) could help.

Comment: Substitution or showing that the integral is convergent for all values of $t$(except 0) would be a start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By $tx=y \implies tdx=dy$

$$\int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin{tx}}{x} d x= \int_0^{t\pi} \frac{\sin{y}}{y} d y$$

which is convergent indeed by integrationby parts

$$\int_0^{a} \frac{\sin{y}}{y} d y=\int_0^{1} \frac{\sin{y}}{y} d y+\int_1^{a} \frac{\sin{y}}{y} d y$$

and

$$\int_1^{a} \frac{\sin{y}}{y} d y=\left[-\frac{\cos y}{y}\right]_1^a-\int_1^{a} \frac{\cos{y}}{y^2} d y$$

and in the limit $a\to \infty$

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin{y}}{y} d y=\frac{\cos 1}{1}-\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos{y}}{y^2} d y$$

and $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\cos{y}}{y^2} d y$ converges absolutely by comparison test with $\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^2} d y$.

Answer (score 1):

With $tx=z$,

$$\lim_{t \to \infty } \int_0^{\pi} \frac{\sin{tx}}{x} d x=\lim_{t \to \infty } \int_0^{t\pi} \frac{\sin{z}}{z} d z= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\sin{z}}{z} d z$$

which is well-known to be $\dfrac\pi2$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral

Comment: I apologise for not making it clear earlier, but I cannot appeal to this fact (that the Dirichlet integral is $\frac{\pi}{2}$).

Comment: @Karl "...but I cannot appeal...".  But you can go to the referenced wiki page, select one of its demonstrations, and master it.  Then, you are solving the problem *from scratch*.  While this approach is often problematic, in this case the math on the referenced wiki page is not that bad.